Is there a way to loop through a custom function to generate multiple ggplot2 graphs in R?
I created a custom function in R to standardize multiple graphs. The function is essentially as follows:
CustomFunction <- function(SpecificEvent) {
     ggplot()+
        geom_point(data = df[df$SpecificEvent])+
        geom_point(data = df2[df2$SpecificEvent])+
        etc.
}

Currently I manually assign the graph created to the global environment:
Graph1 <- CustomFunction(1)
Graph2 <- CustomFunction(2)
Graph3 <- CustomFunction(3)

I am looking for a way to automate this because the number of events that I am graphing is getting out of hand. Is there a way to do this with a for loop and a list? Similar to the following:
for (i in 1:300) {
graph_list <- list()
graph[[i]] <- CustomFunction(i)
}

#Call graph to view or save with:
graph_list[[1]]
ggsave("Graph1.jpeg", graph_list[[1]]) 

I apologize if this doesn't make sense. Please let me know if you need more clarification.
Thanks!

graph_list <- lapply(1:300, CustomFunction) is usually easier. For the for loop you have, you need to place graph_list <- list() outside the loop, and assign to graph_list[[1]] instead of graph[[1]].

Also see the top answer here for some tips for saving lots of plots in a list.

This works great, thanks! But now another layer of complexity. My custom function has two variables, the specific event number and the year in which it occurred. I have a dataframe that counts the number of events in a given year, with two colums: Year and Count.
Is there a way to specify in lapply for each year, run 1:df$count? Replacing the following:
CustomFunction(2, 2021)```

with something such as:

```graph_list <- lapply(1:df$Count, CustomFunction, df$Year)```

It is better to ask a new question. You either want mapply to loop over both count and year, or if you need all combinations, use expand.grid first.

Thank you, again. Apologies for not asking another question.

No worries, it's just hard to discuss specifics in the comments, so a new question is better. Try to always include a minimal and reproducible example with your question.

To use for loop, you could try something like this:
events <- c(1:300)
graph <- paste0("Graph", events, ".jpeg")
for (i in events) {
  CustomFunction(i)
  ggsave(graph[i])
}

